# Active Directory (LDAP) query/filter to retrieve Exchange distribution lists

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

I am looking for an LDAP query that would retrieve Exchange distribution lists.

If I am doing the simple `(objectClass=Group)` I will get too many groups, most of them not useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would use groupType attribute to identify distribution lists.
Here you can find [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) how to tell the difference between security/ distribution.

And filter can look like that:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(!(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)))
```

**EDIT**
alternatively, you may want to check for groups that has e-mail addresses in exchange, smth like:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(proxyAddresses=*))
```

Comment: Any idea how i can use the query to get mail address of distribution lists?

Comment: @LeenaBhandari not sure what you mean. Filter is only responsible for finding the objects. If you want to know properties of the found objects, approach would depend on the tool used. But in general: you'd need to check proxyAddresses property of groups returned.